# Disable swiping in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-button

Since few days I tried to disable the SWIPE. I read so many conversations at stackoverflow, but all this didn't work or was too old. I have a next `Button`. Only with the next `Button` the User should Come to the next `Layout` without swiping.

So have anybody a solution to disable swiping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get something like this working, you will need to create your own subclass of ViewPager.

It should have a new field: e.g.

`private boolean swipeEnabled;`

You will also need to override `onInterceptTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent` and check if the user has currently enabled / disabled the `ViewPager`.

e.g.

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return isEnabled && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Then in your code where you are hosting your `ViewPager` you should have an enable and disable method that change the value of that new field based on your needs.

Make sure in your xml layout you use this new class rather than the default ViewPager class.

Comment: Overriding `onInterceptTouchEvent()` will prevent child views to receive input. In most cases this is __not__ the intended behavior. Besides, you should return __true__ (not false) to signal that event was handled.